# MySQL backfill missing data where records have one common field

Tags: mysql, database

I want to find a way to fill in missing data from records that have data to ones that dont where an email matches.

I have a table where it has name, address, city, state,zip and email.  like this

```
kim,,,55555,kim@domain.com
kim,Longmont,CO,55555,kim@domain.com
kim,,,,kim@domain.com
```

What I want to do is remove duplicates and not lose the relevant data.  So I would like to back fill each record with the data that is there and then remove dupes.  There isn't always a record that has all of the details like the 2nd one.  Sometimes there may not be any record with all of the data.

Ideally I'd want to end up with the following so each record has as many of the fields that are available.  If a field has 2 or more different records I am okay with just filling in from the first.

I hope that's a fair explanation of it

```
kim,Longmont,CO,55555,kim@domain.com
kim,Longmont,CO,55555,kim@domain.com
kim,Longmont,CO,55555,kim@domain.com
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: If you provide code example it will be easier to help you

Comment: @marc_s : OP is begineer and he is yet to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any code so I have to improvise with mine.  I have two tables t1 and t2, where t2 is a exactly copy of t1 (you can try creating a copy of your table or with a self join which I'm not sure if it works with that). It works for me:

```
update t2,t1 set t2.first_name=
case when t2.first_name='' 
then t1.first_name 
else t2.first_name end 
where t2.actor_id=t1.actor_id 
and t1.first_name!='';
```

I did it for one column called first_name. Modify the query and apply it to your table.  So you have 2 options:

1. Add the others table and make one big query.
2. Apply the same query multiple times 1 for each column that you want to change...

here is my example

```
mysql> select * from t2 limit 10;
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name    | last_update         |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|        1 |            | GUINESS      | 2012-06-29 08:36:22 |
|        2 |            | WAHLBERG     | 2012-06-29 08:36:22 |
|        3 |            | CHASE        | 2012-06-29 08:36:22 |
|        4 |            | DAVIS        | 2012-06-29 08:36:22 |
|        5 |            | LOLLOBRIGIDA | 2012-06-29 08:36:22 |
|        6 |            | NICHOLSON    | 2012-06-29 08:36:22 |
|        7 |            | MOSTEL       | 2012-06-29 08:36:22 |
|        8 |            | JOHANSSON    | 2012-06-29 08:36:22 |
|        9 |            | SWANK        | 2012-06-29 08:36:22 |
|       10 | CHRISTIAN  | GABLE        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t1 order by actor_id limit 10;
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name    | last_update         |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE   | GUINESS      | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        1 | a          |              | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|        2 | NICK       | WAHLBERG     | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        3 | ED         | CHASE        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        4 | JENNIFER   | DAVIS        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        5 | JOHNNY     | LOLLOBRIGIDA | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        6 | BETTE      | NICHOLSON    | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        7 | GRACE      | MOSTEL       | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        8 | MATTHEW    | JOHANSSON    | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
|        9 | JOE        | SWANK        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update t2,t1 set t2.first_name=case when t2.first_name='' then t1.first_name else t2.first_name end where t2.actor_id=t1.actor_id and t1.first_name!='';
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 200  Changed: 9  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t2 limit 10;
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name    | last_update         |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|        1 | PENELOPE   | GUINESS      | 2012-06-29 08:37:34 |
|        2 | NICK       | WAHLBERG     | 2012-06-29 08:37:34 |
|        3 | ED         | CHASE        | 2012-06-29 08:37:34 |
|        4 | JENNIFER   | DAVIS        | 2012-06-29 08:37:34 |
|        5 | JOHNNY     | LOLLOBRIGIDA | 2012-06-29 08:37:34 |
|        6 | BETTE      | NICHOLSON    | 2012-06-29 08:37:34 |
|        7 | GRACE      | MOSTEL       | 2012-06-29 08:37:34 |
|        8 | MATTHEW    | JOHANSSON    | 2012-06-29 08:37:34 |
|        9 | JOE        | SWANK        | 2012-06-29 08:37:34 |
|       10 | CHRISTIAN  | GABLE        | 2006-02-15 04:34:33 |
+----------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```